# Changing controller variable from directive and passing it to ng-show - Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to change a controller variable from a directive and then pass its updated value to ng-show. Please see my code below:

Controller:

```
self.menuVisible = false;
```

Directive:

```
icon.bind('click', function(){
    scope.menuCtrl.menuVisible = true;
})
```

**NOTE:** there are lot more code lines in the directive which are not relevant to the question, and this is the reason why I use directive instead of controller function which I could pass with ng-click.

View:

```
<div class="menu-item" ng-show="menuCtrl.menuVisible"></div>
<div class="icon" my-directive></div>
```

Although nothing visible happens on the element click, when I check the menuCtrl.menuVisible in devtools it returns true after the action.

Could you please explain what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this `menu-item` is not shown even when `menuCtrl.menuVisible=true`?

Comment: no, it's not. I just checked with creating a separate function if the controller and apply the function using ng-click. it works and I could use this option, but wanted to know how to do the same using directive. just for future.

Comment: where do you get `menuCtrl` from inside a directive? show the code how it's added the scope

Comment: I can see the controller just using the scope.menuCtrl inside directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you're not updating your variable inside `$digest` loop, try like this:

```
icon.bind('click', function(){
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        scope.menuCtrl.menuVisible = true;
    }
})
```

Comment: Yes, it's true. Need to read about this :) Thanks a lot for your help! It worked!